# Delphi THttpClient: post's IHttpResponse giving encoded string seen in fiddler webview

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, httpclient, fiddler, utf

I have a `THTTPClient` giving a strange response (apparently UTF-16 encoding?) when invoking `lHttpResp.ContentAsString()`.

The string comes through as this:

> 㰀㼀砀洀氀 瘀攀爀猀椀漀渀㴀∀㄀⸀　∀ 攀渀挀漀搀椀渀最㴀∀唀吀䘀ⴀ㄀㘀∀ 猀琀愀渀搀愀氀漀渀攀㴀∀礀攀猀∀㼀㸀਀㰀刀䔀匀唀䰀吀㸀਀    㰀倀䄀夀倀䄀䜀䔀唀刀䰀㸀栀琀琀瀀猀㨀⼀⼀攀攀⸀琀攀猀琀⸀瀀愀礀最愀琀攀眀愀礀⸀挀漀洀⼀䠀漀猀琀倀愀礀匀攀爀瘀椀挀攀⼀瘀㄀⼀栀漀猀琀瀀愀礀⼀瀀愀礀瀀愀最攀⼀㄀㘀㜀　㔀㘀㘀㈀㄀㔀㐀㌀㈀㐀欀䬀䬀儀㔀唀漀䈀椀吀氀㠀䔀爀䈀䴀　戀㰀⼀倀䄀夀倀䄀䜀䔀唀刀䰀㸀਀    㰀匀䔀匀匀䤀伀一吀伀䬀䔀一㸀㄀㘀㜀　㔀㘀㘀㈀㄀㔀㐀㌀㈀㐀欀䬀䬀儀㔀唀漀䈀椀吀氀㠀䔀爀䈀䴀　戀㰀⼀匀䔀匀匀䤀伀一吀伀䬀䔀一㸀਀㰀⼀刀䔀匀唀䰀吀㸀਀

Running Fiddler, I can see the response is fine when looking at the raw or text view, but matches the above encoding when looking at Webview. I'm probably missing something pretty obvious here, but I've tried converting with `TEncoding` to no avail, as per this thread:

[Delphi - converting string back from UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662955/delphi-converting-string-back-from-utf-8)

Fiddler's text view gives a correct text:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<RESULT>
    <PAYPAGEURL>https://url/</PAYPAGEURL>
    <SESSIONTOKEN>1670565241202KKv4NPBBScANOL6rxbi</SESSIONTOKEN>
</RESULT>
```

Comment: Sounds like `THTTPClient` doesn't know the data is encoded as UTF-16 and so decodes the raw bytes using the wrong encoding, giving you [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). What are the values of the `lHttpResp.ContentCharSet` and `lHttpResp.ContentEncoding` properties?  Does the HTTP response's `Content-Type` header specify UTF-16 as its `charset`? Is there a UTF-16 BOM in front of the XML? Without either of those, the client would have to actually parse the XML prolog to discover that UTF-16 is being used. I don't know if `THTTPClient` does that. Indy's `TIdHTTP` does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ContentCharSet is 'UTF-16' whilst ContentEncoding is ''.

Response header is:

HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2022 05:54:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-16
Connection: close
Content-Length: 540

Comment: I'd say that you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case due to wrongly applied (platform-specific) [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):  `x.encode('utf-16-le').decode('utf-16-be')` gives a `xml` string providing that *`x=<your shared string>`*

Comment: @JosefZ `UTF-16` without endianness is still a valid value, because the beginning `<xml` can clearly be recognized as LE or BE. Also [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing) has enough examples so no implementation should be able to fuxx this up, even without BOM.

Comment: @AmigoJack any standard is nice however its implementation could hobble ;)

Comment: This is why Indy's `TIdHTTP` ignores the charset in the `Content-Type` for HTML and XML payloads (and eventually JSON, too) and instead parses the data itself to discover the actual charset and endian used.

Comment: So this worked fine until recently, solution was up and running until something changed on their end. All I know is Tomcat is involved.

I'd considered using Indy's TIdHTTP but thought I may as well just use THTTPClient, possibly a mistake on my part now this issue has arisen. I guess there may be a way to get Delphis XMLDoc.TXMLDOcument to pass the received string using the correct encoding. Any ideas here?

Comment: Additionally, a post from .net's httpwebrequest returns the expected string using basically the same details. Possibly quicker to call a .net dll to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped with this and found it was TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode, it was one of the only ones I hadn't tried due to tunnel vision. Resolution seen below. Thanks for your input.

```
lHttpResp.ContentAsString(TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode); //to get the result in text for testing etc
XmlFile.LoadFromStream(lhttpResp.ContentStream); //to load to an xmlfile
```